# Removing multiple zeros from a string if only zeros are input

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to implement a method that if the user inputs a series of zero like `"00000"` it should return `"0"`

Otherwise, if the user inputs for example `"00009"` or `"90000"`, the input variable should remain unchanged.

Is there a simple solution for this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def doit(str)
  str.squeeze == '0' ? '0' : str
end
```

```
doit("00000") #=> "0"
doit("00009") #=> "00009"
doit("90000") #=> "90000"
```

See the last sentence of the doc [String#squeeze](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-squeeze).

Comment: nice! @Cary Swoveland

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
"0000000".gsub(/^0+$/, '0')
 => "0" 
"0000009".gsub(/^0+$/, '0')
 => "0000009" 
 => "0" 
"9000000".gsub(/^0+$/, '0')
 => "9000000"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using regular expressions as follow:

```rb
def validate_sequence(sequence:)
   r = /\A(^0+[1-9]+\z)|(\A[1-9]+[0-9]+\z)/
   sequence.match?(r) ? sequence : '0'
end
```

The code above returns the same sequence if the sequence matches the regex or 0 in another case, the regex validates that a sequence is a valid number or if end with a valid sequence of numbers, the double `?` change the result of the `match` function and returns a boolean value.

You can use the code above as follow: `validate_sequence(sequence: '0000000')`

If you want to only match digits distinct of 0 at the beginning and at the end you can do it by changing the value of **r** like this: `r = /(^0+[1-9]+$)|(^[1-9]+0+$)/`.

Comment: Note `validate_sequence(sequence: "010") #=> "0"`. My understanding is that `"0"` is to be returned only when all characters in the string are zeros. Regarding your regular expression the capture groups serve no purpose and while end-of-line anchors (`^` and `$`) are OK here, it is generally recommened that end-of-string anchors (`\A` and `\z`) be used to anchor strings. You don't need `!!` as `!!sequence.match(r)` is `false` if and only only if `sequence.match(r) #=> nil` (hence *falsy*, as opposed to *truthy*). `sequence.match?(r) ? sequence : '0'` is perhaps more expressive.

Comment: thx for the good comments @Cary Swoveland, although is not clear for me that "010" is a valid string from my understanding and being fair, is not clear in the question, besides that I agreed that the `?` is more expressive I will edit my answer with that, regarding to the anchors I wasn't aware of that thx for the good advice

Answer (score 1):

When the string always contains only digits then you might want to consider:

```
sequence.to_i.zero? ? '0' : sequence
```

---

IMHO it is always interesting to run a benchmark when there are so many different solutions

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  examples = %w[00000 00001 12345]

  def cary_swoveland(str)
    str.squeeze == '0' ? '0' : str
  end

  def r4cc00n(str)
     r = /(^0+[1-9]+$)|(^[1-9]+[0-9]+$)/
     !!str.match(r) ? str : '0'
  end

  def spickermann(str)
    str.to_i.zero? ? '0' : str
  end

  def ursus(str)
    str.gsub(/^0+$/, '0')
  end

  %w[cary_swoveland r4cc00n spickermann ursus].each do |algorithm|
    x.report(algorithm) { examples.each { |e| send(algorithm, e) } }
  end

  x.compare!
end
```

Result:

```
$ ruby benchmark.rb 
Warming up --------------------------------------
      cary_swoveland    86.149k i/100ms
             r4cc00n    24.258k i/100ms
         spickermann    94.211k i/100ms
               ursus    21.714k i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
      cary_swoveland    833.459k (± 2.2%) i/s -      4.221M in   5.067333s
             r4cc00n    231.787k (± 6.9%) i/s -      1.164M in   5.050636s
         spickermann    905.658k (±10.0%) i/s -      4.522M in   5.097849s
               ursus    213.674k (± 2.3%) i/s -      1.086M in   5.083811s

Comparison:
         spickermann:   905658.0 i/s
      cary_swoveland:   833459.1 i/s - same-ish: difference falls within error
             r4cc00n:   231787.4 i/s - 3.91x  (± 0.00) slower
               ursus:   213674.2 i/s - 4.24x  (± 0.00) slower
```

Comment: Considering that `"x00".to_i #=> 0` you are depending on the string containing digits only (as in the examples). I'm not suggesting it's not a reasonable assumption, but thought it deserved a mention.

Comment: I ran your benchmark and found that `cary_swoveland` was fastest on my 143rd try.